# kdump.conf - file contents remove after trigger crash

Tags: alma-linux, kdump

I have changed the path in kdump.conf from `/var/crash` to `/home/crash/kdump`. System is AlmaLinux 8.

After triggering a crash with `echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger`, the crash dump in still placed in the `/var/crash` folder.

When I checked the kdump.conf file, everything has been cleared from the file. It becomes a blank file.

Answer (score 0):

Once you modify `kdump.conf`, `kdump` needs to restarted. Otherwise if you trigger a crash, everything clears in `kdump.conf` and nothing is saved.

I removed everything from the config file and had this:

```
path /var/crash
core_collector makedumpfile -l --message-level 7 -d 31
```

After restarting `kdump` and triggering a crash, it does not clear the the `kdump.conf` file this time, but dumps are not saved.

Ensure you modify the `kdump.conf` original file and restart `kdump`. It seems once everything has been removed such as the commented values, it does not work. Having all the commented values in the `kdump.conf` file and restarting `kdump` works.

```
#raw /dev/vg/lv_kdump
#ext4 /dev/vg/lv_kdump
#ext4 LABEL=/boot
#ext4 UUID=03138356-5e61-4ab3-b58e-27507ac41937
#nfs my.server.com:/export/tmp
#nfs [2001:db8::1:2:3:4]:/export/tmp
#ssh user@my.server.com
#ssh user@2001:db8::1:2:3:4
#sshkey /root/.ssh/kdump_id_rsa
path /home/crash/kdump
core_collector makedumpfile -l --message-level 7 -d 31
#core_collector scp
#kdump_post /var/crash/scripts/kdump-post.sh
#kdump_pre /var/crash/scripts/kdump-pre.sh
#extra_bins /usr/bin/lftp
#extra_modules gfs2
#failure_action shell
#force_rebuild 1
#force_no_rebuild 1
#dracut_args --omit-drivers "cfg80211 snd" --add-drivers "ext2 ext3"
#fence_kdump_args -p 7410 -f auto -c 0 -i 10
#fence_kdump_nodes node1 node2
```